# send array to golang server using curl

Tags: go, curl

I have a simple HTTP server running. I am trying to send a list of values to this server using curl.

`curl -X POST -d "["student1", "student2"]" http://localhost:8080/`

How can I read the body as a string slice? I tried `b, _ := io.ReadAll(r.Body)` but it reads the array as one item rather than an array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use json decoder to decode the values in slice of string

```
var arr []string
err := json.NewDecoder(req.Body).Decode(&arr)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Fprintf(w,fmt.Sprintf("Error:%+v",err))
    return
}
fmt.Println(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this :P

`curl -X POST -d '["student1", "student2"]' http://localhost:8080`

The quotes were breaking the payload parsing.

This also works:

`curl -X POST -d "[\"student1\", \"student2\"]" http://localhost:8080`

Your go server is probably reciving a payload that looks like this `[student1, student2]` instead of looking like this `["student1", "student2"]`

After you have your well formed json string array being sent, you can parse it like this:

```
var body []string
e := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&body)
fmt.Println(e, body[0]) // nil "student1"
```